# Can Apple Watch track my fitness data while running back and forth on an airplane?

Tags: apple-watch

Can Apple Watch track my fitness data while running back and forth on an airplane?

Comment: Did you try it to see?

Comment: Last time I was on a cruise ship (with wifi and the sky plenty visible for GPS) my iPhone 6s never had a clue where it was... Apple maps and google maps both mapped us at the port (based on IP I'm guessing).  I thought letting Runkeeper post my runs while aboard would be interesting yet Runkeeper crashed every time it was opened.  Best I could do was use the stopwatch to time my laps.